# Oracle audit log to other server?

Tags: oracle, audit

How can I configure audit log records to other server? Because:

1. DB Server is full because it is very big.
2. Our IT team manages DB server and our team (security team) is going to get audit log in our server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[AUDIT_SYSLOG_LEVEL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn10263.htm#REFRN10263)

You can send your audit entries to syslog with the above parameter, and configure syslog for remote logging.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to extend the answer given by Balazs Papp.

Set the `AUDIT_SYSLOG_LEVEL` parameter to specify a `facility`(Part of OS which is logging the message) and `priority`(Severity of the message) in the format `AUDIT_SYSLOG_LEVEL=facility.priority`

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter system set AUDIT_SYSLOG_LEVEL = 'LOCAL1.INFO' scope=spfile;

System altered.
```

Now bounce the database.

Determine which System logger is being used in your server.

```
[root@testsrv Desktop]# ls -d /etc/*syslog*
/etc/rsyslog.conf  /etc/rsyslog.d
```

In my local server I have got rsyslog. 
Edit the rsyslog.conf file to specify remote host as following. It depends upon facility and priority that you have specified for `AUDIT_SYSLOG_LEVEL`.

```
[root@testsrv Desktop]# vi /etc/rsyslog.conf
#For local server
local1.info                                             /var/log/oracle_audit.log
#For remote server
local1.info                                             @@192.168.1.51:514


[root@testsrv Desktop]# service rsyslog restart
```

In the remote server uncomment the following to lines.

```
[root@remotesrv log]# vi /etc/rsyslog.conf 
# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

[root@remotesrv log]# service rsyslog restart
```

To test it I have shutdown my database in the local server.

```
SQL> shut immediate
Database closed.
```

During the shutdown I can see the audit trail in the remote server as shown below.

```
[root@remotesrv log]# tail -f messages
Mar 26 08:33:38 nepal Oracle Audit[9007]: LENGTH : '149' ACTION :[8] 'SHUTDOWN' DATABASE USER:[1] '/' PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA' CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle' CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/1' STATUS:[1] '0' DBID:[0] ''
```